# Make file error when I try to do with linking the test file

Tags: linux, compiler-construction, makefile, shared-objects

I wrote a simple make file

```
test : main.cpp
    g++ -Wall -o $@ $^ -lhello_ext -L. -I/usr/include/python2.7/   -lboost_regex -lpython2.7 -ggdb
libhello_ext.so : hello_ext.o
    g++ -shared -o $@ $^ -Lboost-lib-path -I/usr/include/python2.7/   -lboost_regex -lpython2.7 -ggdb
hello_ext.o : hello_ext.cpp
    g++ -c -Wall -Werror -fpic -o $@ $^ -I/usr/include/python2.7/   -lboost_regex -lpython2.7 -ggdb
.PHONY : clean
clean:
    rm -rf test lib* *.o *.swf
```

But when I do a make I get an error

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lhello_ext
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [test] Error 1
```

Тhe problem in the first two rows and when I delete these commands from a make file and write the manual way to the terminal, it works fine. Тhat is, from the terminal I do

```
g++ -Wall -o $@ $^ -lhello_ext -L. -I/usr/include/python2.7/   -lboost_regex -lpython2.7 -ggdb
```

and everything works fine. What's the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you execute your line directly, `$@ $^` is probably empty (check it yourself using `echo`). In that case, the argument `-lhello_ext` is not interpreted as a linker command for a library to add, but as the output name for your object file. That's why it works on the command line.

As for why it doesn't work in the Makefile: my guess would be that your library `hello_ext` is located in the current directory. For the linker to find it, you need to put your library path information `-L.` *before* you add the library.